# ORA-03114 not connected oracle Visual Basic 6,Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, connection, basic

I have small Visual Basic Application working Under Basis Of Timer in client machine using oracle client.in each and Every 3 minutes Timer will execute and program is triggred.At Each time a new connection is opened to the oracle server and uploading data to the table. But at the forth time an error getting while opening a table in the oracle database using record set "-ORA:03114 not connected to oracle .I using Provider MSDORA.1

Comment: Are you properly closing the connection when done?

Comment: Yes, Every time i closed the connection.